# Remoção item na lista encadeada C

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação, lista-encadeada, allegro

Galera estou com um probleminha bem chatinho, eu estou implementando um A* simples. Quando eu passo o item já verificado para a lista fechada e faço a desalocação do item da lista aberta, está dando erro de ponteiro não declarado... O erro é esse `pointer being freed was not allocated`, mas eu já chequei minha lógica e também chequei se eu estava desalocando um ponteiro que realmente tinha sido declarado com `malloc` e realmente estava! Eu até uso no mesmo código, um outro código de desalocação. Eu praticamente copiei e colei um no outro e no que já estava feito e não dá problemas, mas no novo dá... Vejam:

Esse é o código de desalocação que está funcionando (eu uso esse código para animar também):

```
void anima(Lista* li, int frame, int agFramex, int agFramey){
    Elem* no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    Elem* ant = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    no = (*li);
    ant = no;
    while(no != NULL){
        if(no->dados.y > ALT+200){
            if(no == *li){
                *li = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = *li;
            } else if(no->Prox == NULL){
                ant->Prox = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = ant->Prox;
            } else {
                ant->Prox = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = ant->Prox;
            }
        } else {
            no->dados.y += no->dados.vel;
            al_draw_bitmap_region(no->dados.Img, agFramex*frame, agFramey*frame, frame, frame, no->dados.x, no->dados.y, 0);
            ant = no;
            no = no->Prox;
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é o código que não está: (`atual` e `AbList` existem, estão como parâmetro de função lá em cima, como a função era muito extensa optei por não colocar ela inteira aqui, nos momentos anteriores da função eu coloco elementos na lista apenas isso):

```
Elc* rem = (Elc*) malloc(sizeof(Elc));
Elc* mer = (Elc*) malloc(sizeof(Elc));

rem = (*AbList);
mer = rem;
while(rem != NULL){
    if(rem->dados.x == atual.dados.x && rem->dados.y == atual.dados.y){
        if(rem == *AbList){
            *AbList = rem->Prox;
            free(rem);
            rem = *AbList;
        } else if(rem->Prox == NULL){
            mer->Prox = rem->Prox;
            free(rem);
            rem = mer->Prox;
        } else {
            mer->Prox = rem->Prox;
            free(rem);
            rem = mer->Prox;
        }
    } else {
        mer = rem;
        rem = rem->Prox;
    }
}
```

Como é possível ver, os códigos são muitíssimo parecidos, mas por algum motivo neste eu recebo o erro e no outro não...

**Obs:** Uso Macbook Pro estou codificando em C usando Allegro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponho que `Lista` seja um `Elem*` e que `Lista*` seja um `Elem**`. Correto?

Vamos ver o início da primeira função:

```c
Elem* no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));  // Aloca um elemento
Elem* ant = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem)); // Aloca outro elemento
no = (*li);                               // Perde a referência do no alocado. Memory leak.
ant = no;                                 // Perde a outra referência também. Memory leak.
// Neste ponto no == ant == *li
```

Agora a segunda:

```c
Elc* rem = (Elc*) malloc(sizeof(Elc)); // Aloca um elemento.
Elc* mer = (Elc*) malloc(sizeof(Elc)); // Aloca um elemento.

rem = (*AbList);                       // Perde a referência. Memory leak.
mer = rem;                             // Perde outra referência. Memory leak.
// Neste ponto mer == rem == *AbList
```

Vamos analisar mais da sua primeira função:

```c
            if(no == *li){
                *li = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = *li;
                // Esquece que ant pode ser igual a no.
                // Se for igual, agora ant é um ponteiro inválido!
                // Se for diferente, então ant->Prox é um ponteiro inválido!
```

E também:

```c
            } else if(no->Prox == NULL){
                ant->Prox = no->Prox; // Ou seja, ant->Prox = NULL;
                free(no);
                no = ant->Prox; // Ou seja, no = NULL;
            } else {
                // Este bloco é idêntico ao anterior!
                ant->Prox = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = ant->Prox;
            }
```

Então, nunca deixe o `ant` apontar para nada que não seja o nó anterior de `no`. E no caso de `no` ser o primeiro, que `ant` seja `NULL`. Ou ele tem que apontar para algo válido ou para `NULL`, nunca deixe-o apontando para algo inválido! O mesmo pode ser afirmado sobre `ant->Prox`.

E também, todo código na forma `} else if (x) { A; } else { A; }`, aonde a avaliação de `x` não tem efeitos colaterais, pode ser substituído simplesmente por `} else { A; }`.

```c
void anima(Lista* li, int frame, int agFramex, int agFramey){
    Elem *no = *li;
    Elem *ant = NULL;
    while (no != NULL) {
        if (no->dados.y > ALT + 200) {
            if (no == *li) {
                *li = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = *li;
                // Aqui ant era NULL e continua sendo NULL.
            } else {
                // Se entrou aqui, então ant não é NULL.
                // Isso funciona mesmo se no->Prox for NULL.
                ant->Prox = no->Prox;
                free(no);
                no = ant->Prox;
            }
        } else {
            no->dados.y += no->dados.vel;
            al_draw_bitmap_region(no->dados.Img, agFramex * frame, agFramey * frame, frame, frame, no->dados.x, no->dados.y, 0);
            ant = no;
            no = no->Prox;
        }
    }
}
```

O que muda de verdade no comportamento nesse código acima em relação ao anterior é apenas que os *memory leaks* foram eliminados e que o `ant = no;` do início foi substituído por `Elem *ant = NULL;`.

Podemos aplicar as mesmas transformações na sua segunda função, que tem a mesma estrutura. Esse é o resultado:

```c
Elc* rem = *AbList;
Elc* mer = NULL;

while(rem != NULL){
    if (rem->dados.x == atual.dados.x && rem->dados.y == atual.dados.y) {
        if (rem == *AbList) {
            *AbList = rem->Prox;
            free(rem);
            rem = *AbList;
            // Aqui mer era NULL e continua sendo NULL.
        } else {
            // Se entrou aqui, então mer não é NULL.
            // Isso funciona mesmo se rem->Prox for NULL.
            mer->Prox = rem->Prox;
            free(rem);
            rem = mer->Prox;
        }
    } else {
        mer = rem;
        rem = rem->Prox;
    }
}
```

Ah sim, quase ia esquecendo. Se o endereço de `atual` for alguma coisa que possa aparecer na lista iniciada por `*AbList`, esse segundo código sempre vai dar pau se você chegar em um caso aonde `rem == &atual` e o `free(rem);` for executado e depois você tentar acessar `atual.dados.x` ou `atual.dados.y`. Se isso acontecer, faça uma cópia em algum outro lugar que fique fora da lista e acesse apenas a cópia. Se isso não acontece (ou se `atual` já for exatamente essa cópia), então está tudo tranquilo quanto a isso.